# How to configure the foward/rewind step size (in seconds) in GNOME Videos (totem)?

Tags: video, video-player, totem

I'm using right/left arrows to skip time on Gnome Video but default settings for this are too much

- forward (right arrow + mouse scroll up): 60 seconds
- backward (left + mouse scroll down): 15 second

How I can change it?

I tried googling and looking at the documentation.
Now thanks to Wikipedia I understood that player named as **totem** and I am trying to find configuration files via the terminal.

```sh
$ totem --help-all
```

Unfortunately I don't see anything.

Should I install VLC?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but for those who need this in the future,

1. install 'playerctl' package.

(pacman -Ss playerctl, dnf install playerctl) haven't checked for debian based system (maybe in the repo, so apt install playerctl)

2. now go to settings> keyboard> view and customize shortcuts> custom shortcuts.
   press on + icon
3. 

give in each cell

> move media forward

> playerctl position 5+

and give a custom keyboard shortcut

4. now add another custom shortcut by pressing + and repeat above, but change to

> move media backward

> playerctl position 5-

[above filled in shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHsRB.png)

now close settings and play any video (in gnome video play, vlc or even in browser), press that shortcut it will move video 5sec forward or backward

this will work even without focus
i would also recommend setting (settings> keyboard> view and customize shortcuts> sound and media> Play (or play/pause)

( now you can rewind that one youtube tutorial going too fast without leaving note taking app)